# error while loading shared libraries: libssl.so.1.0.0: cannot open shared object file: in AWS instance

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

Facing this issue while running my application in `64 bit AWS EC2` instance:

> ```
> error while loading shared libraries: libssl.so.1.0.0: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory.
> ```

In normal `ubuntu` we can use this [link](https://askubuntu.com/questions/339364/libssl-so-10-cannot-open-shared-object-file-no-such-file-or-directory) but how to solve using `yum` / something else? Please help.